# Force cursor update?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display a *wait* cursor in my application during a threaded operation.

With

```
 Cursor.Current
```

The cursor is changed for one frame then comes back to default, and I don't know why.

With

```
Application.UseWaitCursor
```

it works properly, but the cursor is sometimes not visually updated until the mouse is moved.

So I add

```
 Cursor.Position = Cursor.Position;
```

and the job is done, but the way of doing it is kinda despicable.

How to do that in an elegant way?

Comment: `Application.UseWaitCursor = true;` or `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;` and then `Application.DoEvents();`?

Comment: Frankly, if Cursor.Position = Cursor.Position works, I rather prefer this solution than Application.DoEvents() a million times.

Comment: Just voted to reopen. This is not dup.